# Numerically stable scheme for the 3 real roots of a cubic

Tags: cubics, floating-point

The text book solution is utterly well-know but I will succinctly write it down to fix the notations. The solution of

$$-x^3+3px+2q=0,$$

when $p^3-q^2>0$ are 3 real roots given by

$$x = 2\sqrt{p}\cos\left(\theta+\frac{2n\pi}{3}\right)$$

for $n=0,1,2$, with

$$\theta = \frac{1}{3}\arctan\frac{\sqrt{p^3-q^2}}{q},$$

with the obvious limits when $q\to0^\pm$.

The problem is obviously that the formula for $\theta$ is not numerically robust, as it may produce a detrimental cancellation in the subtraction under the square root. So my question is: can this be modified into a stable scheme?

Comment: Is the regime with p,q both significant and $p^3$ slightly larger than $q^2$ the problem? The regime where both are small is easier.

Comment: See the series of articles on "How to Solve a Cubic Equation" by James F. Blinn, especially Part 5 -- Back to Numerics.

Comment: For low order polynomials (< ~20 roots) with real coefficients, if you need numerical stability, why not just use the Jenkins-Traub algorithm?

Comment: Nickalls has a slightly modified approach here: http://nickalls.org/dick/papers/maths/cubic1993.pdf  which may help in reformulating your solution to the cubic with 3 real roots.

Comment: Another solution is "To Solve a Real Cubic Equation" by W. Kahan, 
http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Math128/Cubic.pdf

Comment: @Ian My problem is indeed with the former case. Blinn and Nickalls seem like going in the direction I sought, thanks Andy Walls and lhf. Kahan's paper settles for an iterative method, and yes, I know of Jenkins-Traub, but this is another question!

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis Is fused multiply-add available (e.g. standard function `fma()` in C, C++)? This allows for the robust and efficient computation of $ab - cd$ (as shown by Kahan and later researchers), and it seems like this scheme could be modified for the computation of $p^{3} - q^{2}$, although I have not worked through the details. This would take care of subtractive cancellation but not address the issue of potential underflow or overflow in intermediate computation, which would have to be addressed separately by appropriate scaling.

Comment: @njuffa You mean that famous trick of recovering the error on $ab$ with FMA, don't you? I mean, by doing $ab - RN(ab)$ where $RN$ is the rounding operation.

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis Closely related, yes. See: Claude-Pierre Jeannerod, Nicolas Louvet, and Jean-Michel Muller, "Further Analysis of Kahan's Algorithm for the Accurate Computation of $2 \times 2$ Determinants",  *Mathematics of Computation*, Vol. 82, No. 284, Oct. 2013, pp. 2245-2264 ([online](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2013-82-284/S0025-5718-2013-02679-8/))

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis I now have a sequence of 16 operations, including four FMAs, that can compute $p^{3} - q^{2}$ with a maximum error of about 17 ulps (empirically determined bound), provided no overflow / underflow occurs in intermediate computations. Would that suit your needs?

Comment: @njuffa Fantastic! Thanks a lot. Please feel free to write an answer, which would be very useful to a lot of people I am sure, as this does not seem to have been addressed in the literature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ten-operation sequence in the pseudo-code below is inspired by the computation of $ab - cd$ in the following paper:

Claude-Pierre Jeannerod, Nicolas Louvet, and Jean-Michel Muller, "Further Analysis of Kahan's Algorithm for the Accurate Computation of $2 \times 2$ Determinants", *Mathematics of Computation*, Vol. 82, No. 284, Oct. 2013, pp. 2245-2264 ([online](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2013-82-284/S0025-5718-2013-02679-8/))

The algorithm makes use of the fused multiply-add, or `fma`, operation to compute the difference of two products robustly in just four operations:

```
w := d * c
e := fma (-d, c, w)
f := fma (a, b, -w)
r := f + e
```

That algorithm is trivially applicable for the computation of the discriminant when computing the real solutions of a quadratic equation. The use of `fma` allows for efficient implementations of error-free transformations, which result in a head-tail (or double-native) representation of operands that in essence provides twice the native precision. The above algorithm provides for an error bound of 1.5 ulp, provided no overflow or underflow occurs in intermediate computation.

For the computation of $p^{3} - q^{2}$ the above algorithm needs modification to incorporate the cubing, where it is preferred not to explicitly compute it as triple-native precision operand. The sequence below is the most efficient version I managed to create on the double; the worst case error does not appear to exceed 17 ulps as determined by reasonably extensive testing with test cases in which $p^{3}$ is very close in magnitude to $q^{2}$. Higher-accuracy versions at potentially reduced performance are undoubtedly possible.

In the code annotations `w:e`, `s:t`, `u:v` designate head-tail pairs of native precision numbers that represent the exact product of two native-precision operands when summed.

When this pseudo-code is transformed into actual programming code processed by a compiler, it is essential that the compiler is configured to implement the sequence of operations as written. Many compilers will re-associate floating-point expressions at high optimization levels, which may even be the default. The strictest floating-point evaluation mode available should be selected. With the Intel compilers, this is `/fp:strict` or `-fp-model=strict` depending on operating system platform.

```
// w:e = -q*q exactly
w := -q * q
e := fma (-q, q, -w)
// s:t =  p*p exactly
s := p * p
t := fma (p, p, -s)
// s:t * p + w:e = s*p + w + t*p +e = s*p+w + u:v + e = f + u:v + e
f := fma (s, p, w)
u := t * p
v := fma (t, p, -u)
// sum all terms into final result
r := ((e + f) + u) + v
```

Comment: I implemented your solution: I only had time for a few tests but it looks like it fits the specs you announced. Many thanks!

Comment: As a bonus, this looks like a very general technique I had not realised the importance of.