# How would you solve for the complex roots of a polynomial with a greater degree than two?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Lets say we have a polynomial with only complex roots. 
an example would be 
$$9x^6-4x^5+x^4-7x^3+8x^2-8x+7$$
How would one go about finding the roots to this polynomial and factoring it. I know this may seem like just asking for an answer, but I would really like to know the process behind it because I couldn't find anything online that would seem to work.

Comment: Use a black box polynomial root finding algorithm like the Jenkins-Traub algorithm.  Fortran code is available from netlib, toms 493 http://netlib.org/toms/

Answer (score 0):

For the case where the degree is 3 or 4, there are formulae giving the roots. However, these formulae cause some nasty numerical problems, so they have to be implemented very carefully, as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2434354/numerically-stable-scheme-for-the-3-real-roots-of-a-cubic). Actually, even the quadratic formula has numerical problems if you don't code it correctly.

For degrees higher than 4, there are no general closed-form formulae, so you have to use numerical methods. There is a survey of available methods [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm). You shouldn't have to write any code yourself -- the work has already been done by experts, and software libraries are widely available.